# parent div having content pushed in firefox only by child divs scrolling js

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, scroll, height

I have been having the oddest bug in firefox. I have a parent div (divbodycontainer) that is having its content scrolled down the screen when a child div containing a floated div with a base height of 0 is dynamically scrolled using javascript. If you scroll half way down any of the main pages in firefox and refresh the page the parent divs content will jump down. Odd thing is firebug reports no css or code change that could be doing this?

Bug also randomly pops up during fast scrolling.

Tried to fix bug by adding a height style to the javascript function since the bug is tied to the scrolling action.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var ntMin = 0+"px";
            var newTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (newTop <= ntMin){
                newTop = ntMin;
            }
$("#floatPitchButton").stop()
.animate({'top': newTop}, "slow")
document.getElementById('floatPitchButton').style.height = ntMin;
});
```

This idea did not fix my problem? Anyone have any idea whats going on?
Site: [www.webstudioproductions.com](http://www.webstudioproductions.com)

Comment: Please close this question. It looks like I was able to solve the problem by deleting the server js file and re-ftping the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was able to solve the problem by deleting the server js file and re-ftping the file.